# change User perspective in code python

Tags: python, select

[image]
see picture above

[image]

When I click a armature,  its name changes at "User Perspective" (see the two pictures above).

I use `bpy.data.armature["Armature"].bones["RightHand"].select = True` to select, but the "RightHand" name is not changed at "User Pespective".

What code can do it?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with 3 lines of code:

`oba = bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones['RightHand'].bone`
`bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = oba` # set active bone
`bpy.context.object.data.bones.active.layers[1] = True`